# Report for users with and without Activities shows Record Count (1) for users without Activities

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I created a report that shows Users with Activities from this week. It groups records by Full Name and for Users with Activities, it shows a correct number of records. For Users without Activities, it shows record count (1) instead of (0). Is it possible to fix it? The report is created from custom report type (Users with or without related records from Activities (Assigned To)) without any customizations except date range.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

It's because your custom report type basically says "with or without" the child record. So the parent records are always shown, whether or not they have child records.

I haven't tried this, but I think you might be able to filter out users without activity by the blank Subject column.